# How did scientists prove that electron configuration was true if we do not know exactly where electrons are?

Tags: orbitals, electronic-configuration

In Wikipedia, there is an [entry for electron configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration)
which explains all about them, but I did not find from this article how they were discovered. If we take into account Schrodinger's quantum mechanical model and Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, then we can only know where electrons are most likely to be, not their location. Can someone clarify if that means that we know they are in a specific sublevel but not its exact location (i.e., it's in 3p somewhere...??). Or are the configurations just a model, to help us understand that electrons have different energies, as mentioned in a closed question ([Determining electronic configuration](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138686/determining-electronic-configuration))?

Comment: You can know the electron is in an orbital without knowing its spatial position. Kind of the point of quantum mechanics, actually.

Comment: What's this supposed to be, "what is this quantum mechanics all about?" question? You should be well aware what electron configuration (and orbital!) is before asking how it can be determined.

Comment: You may consider protecting yourself and vaccinate against microbes, even if you don't know  the microbe structure.

Answer (score 3):

There's an either-or statement in your question that you can remove. An electron configuration is a simplified representation of an approximate model of the actual electronic structure. It is an abstraction that attempts to represent some relevant properties of the electrons in the atom. All electrons have the same rest mass, intrinsic angular momentum and charge, but their energy, the magnitude and orientation of angular momentum, and the orientation of intrinsic angular momentum (spin) can differ.

There is one wavefunction that describes the entire atom. Single electron atoms can be described approximately using an extension of the hydrogenic formula (obtained by applying the Born-Oppenheimer approximation to the Schrodinger equation for the system of electrons and nucleus and solving the resulting differential equation) by simply altering the nuclear mass. For multi-electron atoms, further approximations are necessary. Perhaps the simplest that can be made is to express the wavefunction as a product of single-electron wavefunctions. This is where electronic configurations come in. They can be interpreted as shorthand notation for a product of single-electron wavefunctions.

However this (the information in the electron configuration) only gets you so far.

Electrons are also indistinguishable fermions and the wavefunction of a multi-electron system is a fermionic wavefunction, which has particular anti-symmetric properties under electron exchange (if you put labels on the electrons in the wavefunction, swapping a pair changes the sign of the wavefunction). This requirement can be accommodated by writing the electronic wavefunction of a multielectronic atom as a sum of permutations of the product of single-electron spin-orbitals (see for instance Hartree-Fock theory and Slater determinants).

In addition, the electronic wavefunction is known to be complicated by electron-electron interactions. As soon as you add more electrons that hydrogenic formula loses accuracy, even if Slater showed that it can be used semi-empirically to make some very reasonable predictions. It's *good enough* for some of us, as an old teacher of mine used to say.